# How to compare columns A/B, and return value from column A that does not match B

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am running into an issue trying to compare values from column A and B.  The end result is to have any value in column A that does not have a match in column B, to appear in column C.

The formula I am using is simple and just =IF(A2=B2, "Y", "N")

My issue is that I am unsure of how to compare the entire A column to the entire B column for matches and not row by row.  I only want to see values returned in column C that are in Column A, but not in Column B.

There are about 150,000 rows of data here.

[image]

Comment: can the match be anywhere in column b or does it need to be in the same row?

Comment: What "issue" are you running into? Show the code you've tried and what error or incorrect output you're getting.

Comment: It can be anywhere in the columns I just arranged them side by side for comparison. @Kevin

Comment: @AlexImperiale Check my edited answer

Comment: @AlexImperiale i don't understand why you are not getting the correct results.  See my latest edit. I posted an image of the results I am getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using a vlookup.
Formula for column C2 (apply it for entire column C) - `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,B$1:B$13,1,FALSE)),A1,"")`

You can modify the table range "B$2:B$13" depending on the actual table.

Comment: This does the opposite of what Alex wants.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will get you what you want:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,A1)=0,A1,"")
```

Edit:
Here is an example of the results I am getting.
[image]

Comment: This is showing them all as a match compared to actually showing me which values are unique to column A